# Python - Counter For Column In CSV File

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter, logfile

I'm auditing a SecurityLog CSV file and I have to count the most common event ID number for both the "audit Successes" and "audit failures. I can find the most occurring event ID for the whole file but not for each one. My script isn't the most efficient or perfect, but I can't find any way to do this.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
with open('SecLog.csv') as csvfile:    #Open Security Log
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')


    data = list(readCSV) #to get number of entries in entire log
    row_count=len(data)-1

    data = open('SecLog.csv').read()
    SucCount = data.count('Success') #counts the occurences of "Successes"
    FailCount = data.count('Failure') #counts the occurences of "failures"

    print "Number of Audit Failures:", FailCount, "Failures of", row_count, "entries"
    print "Number of Audit Successes:", SucCount,"Successes of", row_count, "entries"
```

SECURITY LOG: 
Keywords,Date and Time,Source,Event ID,Task Category
Audit Success,3/1/2018 4:52:36 PM,Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing,4798,User Account Management,"A user's local group membership was enumerated.

Subject:
    Security ID:        DESKTOP-1PQOUT8\Mack Naylor
    Account Name:       Mack Naylor
    Account Domain:     DESKTOP-1PQOUT8
    Logon ID:       0x26723

User:
    Security ID:        DESKTOP-1PQOUT8\Mack Naylor
    Account Name:       Mack Naylor
    Account Domain:     DESKTOP-1PQOUT8

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x1e14
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe"
Audit Success,3/1/2018 4:52:10 PM,Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing,4798,User Account Management,"A user's local group membership was enumerated.

Subject:
    Security ID:        DESKTOP-1PQOUT8\Mack Naylor
    Account Name:       Mack Naylor
    Account Domain:     DESKTOP-1PQOUT8
    Logon ID:       0x26723

User:
    Security ID:        DESKTOP-1PQOUT8\Mack Naylor
    Account Name:       Mack Naylor
    Account Domain:     DESKTOP-1PQOUT8

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x1e14
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe"
Audit Success,3/1/2018 4:51:41 PM,Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing,4672,Special Logon,"Special privileges assigned to new logon.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       SYSTEM
    Account Domain:     NT AUTHORITY
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Privileges:     SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
            SeTcbPrivilege
            SeSecurityPrivilege

Comment: share a snippet of the file please

Comment: There, its just a simple windows security log

Comment: That doesn't look like a csv file

Comment: I'm confused because you have `Task Category Audit Success` and `Audit Success`, and it definitely does not look like a `csv`

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to find the most occuring event ID for the whole file, why not sort the CSV by successes/failures and then split to two datasets. Then you can find the most occuring event ID by the same aforementioned method for each dataset respectively.

Comment: Thats what I couldn't figure out how to do, this is my first time scripting and we didn't go over this in class, our professor literally just said figure it out